# Raw SQL in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I am try to perform a RAW SQL query in django.  I am having some trouble getting the fetchall result to output a list of the distinct items in a column.

So I am hoping to get a list of all the items in a column.

```
class TableObject (object):

    def __init__ (self, Kingdom):
        SQL_str_Table = "SELECT DISTINCT column_title FROM sql_table"
        cursor.execute(SQL_str_Table, [])
        listOfReturns = cursor.fetchall()

        for each in listOfReturns:
            item = each
```

when I try a print out of "item" I get:

"bound method TableObject.write of mysite.forms.veiws.TableObject object at 0x03E5EE70"

So my question is how do I get the fetchall result into a list.

Comment: "mysite.forms.veiws.TableObject" ? Show us that code.

Comment: Please, add more information so we can help you. What is this "TableObject" for? Would you want to use a Django model instead? Because there is a really easy solution to "get a list of all the items in a column" using a django model, but i'm not undestanding the problem you have. Please, add all the information you can to help us understand your problem and to give you a solution to it.

Comment: Try debugging listOfReturns what kind of object do you have, what do you have access to in listOfReturns.

Comment: What did you try..post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a flat list of only column_title's then you can do this:

```
listOfReturns = cursor.fetchall()
listOfReturns_flat  = [i for i in listOfReturns if i[0]] #remove empty results if any
```